# ¿Cómo setear la hora actual en un jqxDateTimeInput?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo esto en mi código

```
$("#jqxDateTimeInput").jqxDateTimeInput({
culture: 'es-ES',
width: '55%',
textAlign: "center",
formatString: 'HH:mm tt',
showTimeButton: true,
showCalendarButton: false
});
```

Pero en mi formulario aparece la hora en blanco. ¿Alguien sabe cómo puedo setearle la hora actual?

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con esto:

```javascript
$('#jqxDateTimeInput').jqxDateTimeInput('setDate', new Date());
```

pues el parámetro del método `setDate()` de [jqxDateTimeInput](https://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/jqxdatetimeinput/index.htm#demos/jqxdatetimeinput/) debe ser un objeto [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) de javascript, y para conocer la hora actual no se le pasan parámetros a dicho objeto.